# why dose debug break point not hitting on my lamda function (java8 use idea)?

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

Version:IDEA 2019.3
        JDK8

Tried methods :

1. I'm trying to wrap it in curly braces
2. Globally, only one breakpoint is hit,None of them took effect

The program goes directly to the saving method,

```
    public <V0 extends Rmap> Output<V0> prior(Trans<V0, Rmap> conv) {
        return saving(ds0 -> {
            enqueue((DSdream) ds0.map((Function<Rmap, Rmap>) row -> {
                Rmap r = conv.apply((V0) row);
                return Rec.of(r, tds.get(r.table().toString()));
            }, f));
        });
    }
```

How do I stop at the lambda break point?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code inline, **never** post a screenshot of your IDE.

Comment: Did you ensure that the code on breakpoint line is actually executed? When you launched the debug session - check that the breakpoint has [verified](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-icons) states. Try build | Rebuild action before launching the debug. Check breakpoint settings - that is has **suspend** [property](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#properties) enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use an anonymous inner class that would normally stop at the breakpoint,

```
    @Override
    public <V0 extends Rmap> Output<V0> prior(Trans<V0, Rmap> conv) {
        Output<Rmap> saving = saving(new Consumer<DSdream>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(DSdream dSdream) {
                enqueue((DSdream)
                        dSdream.map((Function<Rmap, Rmap>) row -> {
                            Rmap r = conv.apply((V0) row);
                            return Rec.of(r, tds.get(r.table().toString()));
                        }, f));
            }
        });
        return (Output<V0>) saving;
    }
```

Presumably, after decompiling, lambda is compiled into inner class,
So the break point cannot be located .
It should be the disadvantage of lambda

Comment: There is no decompiling happening. Further, lambda expressions are compiled to methods of their containing class. There is no problem with break points in lambda expressions. Your problem is a logical one; since the `accept` method is not invoked before the invocation of the `saving` method, a breakpoint within the `accept` method can’t be hit before the invocation either. An anonymous inner class doesn’t change that.

Comment: I have a little confusing, lambda is not sequential execution ?

Comment: Since I don’t know what your `saving` method does, I can’t say whether it will execute the consumer’s code sequentially or not. It might even be possible that the method doesn’t call it at all. What is for sure, your `prior` does not call the `accept` method (or do you see an `accept` call in your code?). You are creating the object and passing it to the `saving` method and perhaps, the `saving` method will invoke methods on it. So, of course, no breakpoint will be hit before entering the `saving` method.

Comment: I get your mean. The code is too big to copy out, I should abstract the problem to small demo.